# Enzo SQL shard library and MongoDB's sharding

Tags: mongodb, azure-sql-database, sharding

I know about the sharding mechanism in MongoDB..However I just came to know that MySQL can also support sharding by a library called Enzo SQL shard library. 
http://enzosqlshard.codeplex.com/
http://searchcloudcomputing.techtarget.com/tip/Sharding-relational-databases-in-the-cloud
How can a relational database be sharded while being strongly consistent? Or is it some capability offered only in the cloud? How does it compare with MongoDB's sharding?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question "How can a relational database be sharded while being strongly consistent?" is described in this white paper: http://www.codefutures.com/database-sharding/

Sharding function better and more applicable to cloud base DB because of their usage criteria however it is not limited to cloud as it can be done with on-premise db as if needed. Once usage criteria is defined and limitations are not an issue, sharding is the option to meet highly scalable, less costly, and performant database.

For SQL Database (previously known as SQL Azure) you don't need a library for sharding instead you can do it directly with your database and let application to use ADO.NET properly to access Sharded DB. The details process is described here:
[How to Shard with Windows Azure SQL Database](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1926.how-to-shard-with-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx)

Unfortunately I can not comment on comparison between these two.